# Simple case of __init__.py and import giving mysterious module not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I've tried this from so many different angles but can't sort it out. Must be such a  simple case. In Python 3.7.6:

Directory structure:

```
./modtest/
./modtest/__init__.py
./modtest/test1.py
./modtest/test2.py
```

test1.py:

```
import modtest
def x(i):
   print(i)
   y(i)
```

test2.py:

```
def y(i):
   print(i)
```

`__init__.py` is an empty file.

When I attempt to run the code:

```
$ /Users/pitosalas/miniconda3/bin/python /Users/pitosalas/mydev/rsb_py/modtest/test1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pitosalas/mydev/rsb_py/modtest/test1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import modtest
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modtest
```

From what I read this should've worked. I'm sure there's something trivial wrong!

Comment: Does it work if you put anything at all in `__init__.py` – say, a comment?

Comment: From your command line it's not clear what the current working directory is when you run `test1.py`. For `modtest` to be in the Python search path, you probably need to be running from the parent directory (the one that contains the `modtest` directory).

Comment: @Blckknght so the issue is what directory I am in when I run python xxx and not what directory the file itself is in?

Comment: Why do you need to import modtest? In the example you gave, it's not even used.

Comment: @wjandrea right.. Typo. Let me fix.

Comment: @pitosalas `y` is not going to be defined from importing `modtest`. Did you mean `from modtest.test2 import y`? Also `print(y(i))` is always going to be `None`. Maybe you meant just `y(i)`?

Comment: Yes on the first... I tried many permutations, e.g. import modest and import modest.test2 and from modest.test2 import y. None seemed to work. But your answer below and my response to it I think helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing `modtest` in `test1.py` while this module itself resides inside of `modtest`. This can't be because `modest` wouldn't have yet been defined and added to the search path. So this is what you should have actually:

```
./modtest/
./modtest/__init__.py
./modtest/
./modtest/test2.py
./test1.py  # this module must be outside of modtest
```

Comment: So the key is that the name of the outer "package" (right term?) is not known by code inside it. And importing another module (file.py) inside the same package cannot be qualified by the package name...?

Comment: This isn't right. You absolutely can run a file from within a package that imports other parts of the package. It's probably a bad idea to use `python package/module.py` to do it, `python -m package.module` is better. But it does work.

Comment: @blckknght could you explain what you Nena by package/module.py and python -m ... etc?